# issues with cx_freeze and python 3.2.2?

Tags: python, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze a python 3.2.2 script with cx_freeze 4.2.3. PyQt4 is used by the source script, I'm not sure if that is a potential source of the issue. Python crashes during the build process. Here is the command line output:

> > C:\Python32\New Folder>python setup.py build
> >
> > running build
> >
> > running build_exe
> >
> > copying C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe -> build\exe.win32-3.2\app.exe
> >
> > copying C:\WINDOWS\system32\python32.dll -> build\exe.win32-3.2\python32.dll

Python itself crashes in Windows at this point and gives the "send error report" MS dialog:

> python.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry
>   for the inconvenience.

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

GUI2Exe_Target_1 = Executable(
    script = "script.pyw",
    initScript = None,
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    targetName = "app.exe",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    appendScriptToExe = False,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    icon = "icon.png"
    ) 
excludes = ["pywin", "tcl", "pywin.debugger", "pywin.debugger.dbgcon",
        "pywin.dialogs", "pywin.dialogs.list", "win32com.server",
        "email"] 
includes = ["PyQt4.QtCore","PyQt4.QtGui","win32gui","win32com","win32api","html.parser","sys","threading","datetime","time","urllib.request","re","queue","os"] 
packages = [] 
path = [] 
setup(
    version = "1.0",
    description = "myapp",
    author = "me",
    author_email = "email@email.com",
    name = "app",
    options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes,
                             "excludes": excludes,
                             "packages": packages,
                             "path": path
                            }
               },
    executables = [GUI2Exe_Target_1]
    )
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

edit: After some experimentation it appears the icon I am trying to use is causing issues. It will build if I leave out the icon setting.

Comment: I found this topic while searching, have a look at this link it has the full setup.py, i tried it and it work now, but need a few adjustments [cxFreeze](http://wiki.wxpython.org/cx_freeze)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently cx_freeze wants icons to be in .ico format. If you try to use a .png for an icon the build process will crash. Also, simply renaming the file extension from .png to .ico does not work, you have actually convert the file to ico.

This may have been obvious to some people but the [online docs](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html) don't go into detail about required formats for icons.

Comment: I'm working on [better docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for cx_Freeze. If you want to add some info about this, start with the source [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/takluyver/cx-freeze). For that matter, if you can fix this to at least give a better error message, it would be welcome.